# Admob TestAds not showing anymore

Tags: android, admob

without changing anything the `testads of admob` doesn't show up anymore.

In my `onCreate`:

```
AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice("8xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx7")
            .build();
            mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

i added `addTestDevice` because it thought it will solve my issue, but before it showed testads even without that line..

my XML:

```
<RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/ad_wrapper" 
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
                        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
                                android:id="@+id/adView"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                ads:adSize="BANNER"
                                ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
                        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
                </RelativeLayout>
```

Due to `wrap_content` of my `ad_wrapper` i know there is a "transparent-box" in the `AdView` because when i run my program, `ad_wrapper` got the height of the `ad-banner-size`...

My LogCat:

```
01-05 23:16:37.616: D/dalvikvm(14986): open_cached_dex_file : /data/data/com.android.myapp/cache/ads-1555443625.jar /data/data/com.android.myapp /ads-1555443625.dex

01-05 23:16:37.635: D/dalvikvm(14986): DexOpt: --- BEGIN 'ads-1555443625.jar' (bootstrap=0) ---
01-05 23:16:37.826: D/dalvikvm(14986): DexOpt: --- END 'ads-1555443625.jar' (success) ---
01-05 23:16:37.838: D/dalvikvm(14986): DEX prep '/data/data/com.android.myapp/cache/ads-1555443625.jar': unzip in 0ms, rewrite 201ms
01-05 23:16:48.318: I/dalvikvm(14986): Could not find method android.webkit.WebView.evaluateJavascript, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.o.a.evaluateJavascript
01-05 23:16:48.331: I/webkit/webview_proxy(14986): WebView() constructor=com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.o.a{41fac6d0 VFE.HV.. ......I. 0,0-0,0}
```

**My Device: Alcatel OneTouch 6040X 4.4.2**

On every `Emulator` with API 14+ which i am targeting and another device which i got access to(`HTC`) it is working.

**My questions** due to that it has already worked on my phone and i just want to make sure that real ads are being displayed when i publish my app:

Can i show real ads without having my app published and without clicking them(avoiding conflict with Google admob privacy)?

If so, how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the test device ID corresponds to the **emulator ID** you are using to test your application.

Yes you can program while showing real ads, **however**, it is not recommended because of Admob policy.

In order to show real ads just quit the Test Device ID and put the code like this in the:

```
AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
            mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Also in the XML file, Make sure you put the **Ad Unit ID** they give you when you create a new ad unit in the Admob page or else, you will get an error.

Comment: It's correspondending. The funny Thing is it did work like a charm before. Even without that `testDeviceId` just like you put the code example... The Problem will be at Google side.. I will try now with a real ad. Do you know, i unfortunately set up the ad with Google analytics and since now i don't like admob anymore. They force this Setting and i can't Change it anymore. Am i now forced to implement the tracker? Do i Need the tracker or do i get the most importan data like Revenue and fill rate and impressions and so on even with out tracking? Thanks for your answere

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved,

it has nothing to do with `addTestDevice("8xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx7")`. It also works without this line. It is just important that you provide the `testbanner-ad_unit_id`.

I solved this issue just by treating my phone like Windows, a simple reboot and everything works again.